# EC2 Instance cannot connect to ECS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Helo,
I have empty AWS ECS Cluster but I am unable to put instances into it.
I wanted to use Launch templates and Autoscaling Group, but I am unable to assign created EC2 Instance.

The issue is in shown in `ecs-agent.log`

```
level=error time=2020-10-17T23:23:37Z msg="Unable to register as a container instance with ECS: RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post \"https://ecs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" module=client.go
level=error time=2020-10-17T23:23:37Z msg="Error registering: RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post \"https://ecs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" module=agent.go
```

Notes:

- Using AMI `ami-0eff571a24849e852`
- Cluster name: `debug`
- Region is `eu-central-1`
- Instance has no public IP
- Instance is in `10.10.100.0/24` subnet (`10.10.100.14`) and VPN subnet is `10.10.0.0/16`
- Instance can reach the internet through NAT Instance:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-100-14 ecs]$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.212.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ams15s21-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=109 time=50.1 ms
64 bytes from ams15s21-in-f142.1e100.net (216.58.212.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=109 time=40.1 ms
```

- DNS to outside is resolving fine

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-100-14 ecs]$ nslookup google.com
Server:     10.10.0.2
Address:    10.10.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.212.142
```

- Just to be sure, I have created Endpoints from VPC and Subnet where Instance is to ECS
  [image: VPC-Endpoints]
- I have attached the security group with no restrictions for test
  [image: security-group]
- `ecs.config`:

```
ECS_CLUSTER=debug
ECS_BACKEND_HOST=
```

- I have gone through [https://aws.amazon.com/.../ecs-agent-disconnected/](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-agent-disconnected/), everything is OK
- IAM Role attached has policy `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role`
- ECS Endpoint is resolved fine

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-100-14 ecs]$ nslookup ecs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Server:     10.10.0.2
Address:    10.10.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ecs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.10.100.219
```

**Does anyone have any suggestions?**

Comment: Your ECS cluster is called `debug`? Also can you go to ECS Console and look into `Events` what does it report?

Comment: @Marcin yes, cluster name is `debug`... for debug :) Where can I see `Events`? I have no services, so I believe there will be no events for now.

Comment: Have you inspected `/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log`?

Comment: @Marcin sure, you can find the output on the beginning of my question

Comment: The security groups you've posted are for instance or your VPC interface endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue.

The problem was caused by VPC Endpoints. I placed them in the wrong subnet and security group.

I have moved them to the public subnet (*next to NAT Instance*) and in the same group as NAT Instance (*allow incoming traffic from sg where my EC2 is*).

According to docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints.html

> The security group attached to the VPC endpoint must allow incoming connections on port 443 from the private subnet of the VPC.

Comment: I added an `All Traffic` rule for the security group I was configuring.